# If statement for vannila commandblocks in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

Just simply question...  How do I check if player has a scoreboard point and if he have any, execute a command. Basically how to translate into command blocks something like this:

```
scoreboard_check():
    if @p has (x=! 0) in "scb":
        return (other_command() @p)
    else:
        return (yet_another_command()@p)
```

Comment: Also, just in case you have in-game questions, make sure you post them in https://gaming.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[scores={ObjectiveName=min..max}]` to a target to check for a score (could have just read on the minecraft wiki about [scoreboard](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Objectives) and [execute](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/execute#Bedrock_Edition))